# Monitor not "waking up", not sure if hardware or settings

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep, wake-up

Running Win 7. After manually putting computer to sleep, oftentimes when I move the mouse to wake up, the screen remains black and I can't hear computer ramping up. Does not happen all of the time. Any suggestions? Is this a settings or hardware issue?

Answer (score 3):

Generally to wake up the computer from Sleep you should use keyboard input of some sorts. That is, press the ESC, ENTER or SPACEBAR.

If you're running a wireless mouse chances are that the mouse is also going to sleep as it is not receiving any input while the computer is sleeping.

Now, if the only component that is not waking up is the screen (and the computer IS) then you should check out your Graphics Card's energy-saving settings.